# Get Data from Database using array value as search key -

Tags: laravel

Good Morning.. I stuck at one point where i need to search and get the data from database from array value as key.
Let me Explain - Ref image for table - Under buffaloID - i have 1 record on each day for each buffaloID. so next day buffaloID repeat with new data. I need to get data of 7 days for totalmilk for each buffaloID.
Now i stuck as buffaloID are changing when new member added or deleted.
So i make array of buffaloid so from array i can search each buffaloID and get required data.
Code to get array -

```
               $getbuffaloID = DB::table('Buffalomilkrecord')
                               ->select('buffaloID')
                               ->groupBy('buffaloID')
                               ->pluck('buffaloID')->toArray();;
Ourput is 
array:3 [▼
       0 => "Buffalo-01"
       1 => "Buffalo-02"
       2 => "Buffalo-03"
      ]
```

So let me help to complete the code....

I hope i explain my required clearly. and thanks in advance ...

[image]

Comment: maybe take a look at https://spatie.be/index.php/docs/laravel-query-builder/v5/introduction

Comment: If you just want to get all rows with Buffalo-01, Buffalo-02 and Buffalo-03 you can get them with `->whereIn('buffaloID',$BuffaloArray)`. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses